# webpack Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I've been using `webpack` and `node` for my react application.

My webpack.config.js looks like this

```
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'css/[contenthash].css',
        allChunks: true
    }),
    /* extract vendor files into chunk */
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: module => module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1
    }),
    /* extract webpack runtime into manifest to avoid the manifest being exported into the vendor output */
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "manifest",
        chunks: ["main", "vendor"],
        minChunks: Infinity
    })
```

When i run `npm start` i'm getting below error on my console.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
        at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js:53)
        at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:5)
        at __webpack_require__ (manifest.js:53)
        at webpackJsonpCallback (manifest.js:24)
        at main.js:1
    __webpack_require__ @ manifest.js:53
    (anonymous) @ main.js:5
    __webpack_require__ @ manifest.js:53
    webpackJsonpCallback @ manifest.js:24
    (anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Comment: Please post your index.html with the script tags.
This error is related to the loading order of your chunks.

You can use async=false attribute on your script tag to prevent asynchronous loading of your chunks.

Comment: I am having the same issue - did you ever resolve this?